# Who approves edits?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

When I edit a question or retag it, I am told that my edit has been placed in queue for peer-review. Can anyone please tell me who can accept or decline my edit?

Thanks.I am just curious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll copy the relevant part from [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) (meta.SO).

> #### Who can vote on a suggested edit?
>
> - The owner of a post may vote to accept or reject any modification of their post.
> - All users with the [edit privilege](https://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit) may vote on suggested edits to posts.
> - Users with [5000 rep](https://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) may vote on suggested edits to tag wikis.
> - Two accept or reject votes are required to remove the suggested edit from the queue and either apply the edit to the post or discard it. [It used to be a single vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151586/59303)

See also the [tag-wiki](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/suggested-edits/info) for the [suggested-edits](/questions/tagged/suggested-edits) tag for some more details and useful links.

Comment: I should do a bit more research before posting.

Comment: @Chris I don't think having this information here will do any harm. I guess there are more users, who will learn something new here.

Comment: "The owner of a post may vote to accept or reject any modification of ***her*** post." (Methinks "their" is better.)

Comment: Why the edit? It is quite common nowadays to use the feminine personal pronoun as the 'general' one.

Comment: @GregorBruns - Yes, "their" is certainly not grammatically correct. However, why not use the masculine personal pronoun we've been using for hundreds of years?

Comment: @FineMan Why don't just use "his/her"?